# Drawing with Canvas: Bitmap or point primitives?

Tags: android, graphics

My Android app takes microphone input and plots the amplitude data with points. Right now I'm using Canvas to draw point primitives representing each value, and I'm seeing very slow drawing times. Is this because of all the separate points I'm drawing? Could this be sped up by using a bitmap? If not, is there some other way to bring some speed into this app?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's faster drawing with Bitmap.